# Make github the intermediate between local project and public one to manage website

Tags: git, github

I'm new with github and I'd like to ask if is it possible to make github "is the intermediate" between my website project in local and the website id public server. So can I do this ?

1. Link the local project to repo github with "remote"
2. Link the public project to same github repository
3. Do changes in  local and push them to git repo.
4. Pull changes from git repo to the public project.

Since I am new to git, I would like to know if this method works well or not, if so can you tell me what are the commands and the steps?

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/articles/f1-u3-github-pages - is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @muka.gergely that is not what they are asking

Comment: Why do you need an intermediate repo at Github? Why not create one directly at the website's host?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but I guess what you mean is something that does happen at open source projects very often.

Someone starts a project, let's call it AppX. Everyone can fork that project, so it becomes your own repository. You can use that own repository to push your own changes to. But if you think it might be interesting for AppX (original), you can also request a pull request from the original AppX project, so it will basically pulls in your code from your forked repository into the original repository (after it's accepted by the one who has the permissions)

Comment: Above was one interpretation of your question. I could also imagine you meant the following: You have a repository on Git and you want the changes you pushed to the repository to be deployed automatically. So for example a change to a webpage. You can build pipelines for that, with Travis for example. It will detect changes on a specific branch, which will trigger a script, for example upload to FTP/S3 for example (but you can also think of automated tests et cetera).

Comment: @phd ,  I have made some tests in local. I have created two directories called work and production and I have created a repository in github.
I do changes in directory work and I push them to github then I do pull inside production folder and it works fine.
Is that enough ? is it correct ? If is correct so I don't need to create a folder mywebsite.git on the servere and do git init --bare and hooks .... ?

https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially what you described is what you do, you create a github repo for your project, push the local code to the repo, then in production (ie public) you'd clone the github repo to the location of where the project is and pull with git.

Comment: Hi thaks. I have made some tests in local. I have created two directories called work and production and I have created a repository in github.
I do changes in directory work and I push them to github then I do pull inside production folder and it works fine.
Is that enough ? and is it correct ?

Comment: If is correct so I don't need to create a folder mywebsite.git on the server and do git init --bare and hooks.... ?  https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa

Comment: Correct you don't need to create mywebsite.git folder, just clone

git clone <pathtogithubrepo>  <myproductiondirectoryname>

I suggest not deleting your existing production directory, maybe create a new one with the git clone and change your webserver config to point to it.